# Inequality involving Holders Inequalities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ for some $p>2$, show that $||f||_{p}\leq ||f||_2^{2/p}||f||_{\infty}^{1-2/p}$

I tried to write $|f|^p=|f|^{\frac{p}{2}}|f|^{\frac{p}{2}}$ then apply holders for $1$ and $\infty$ but then I got: 
$$\int |f|^p\leq \int |f|^{\frac{p}{2}}\cdot ||f||_{\infty}$$

Answer (score 3):

$||f||_{\infty}$ acts as an essential bound on the absolute value of $f$, exceeded, if at all, on a set of measure zero.

so $g = \frac{f}{||f||_{\infty}}$ may be treated as a function whose absolute value does not exceed unity, and the proposition to be proved now becomes:
$$
||g||_p^p \le ||g||_2^2
$$
(interpreting the RHS as $\infty$ if $f$ is not square integrable)

Comment: Thanks, now I felt embarss to ask this. This is easy lol. Thanks for your answer

Comment: no need to feel embarrassed! we are all here to help each other. personally i've always had an aversion to thinking about $L^p$ spaces for the very silly reason that the norm integrals very seldom have an explicit answer and surds are sometimes rather formidable-looking! i think this prejudice came in because of the way integration was taught in school, as a kind of set of puzzles. but identifying and isolating these blind spots then working to correct them is, for me at least, quite a good guide to making gradual progress in my understanding. wish you all the best with your studies!